# Wifi camera support for Kindle Fire

Tags: smart-home, digital-cameras, home-security

Which outdoor Wifi cameras with internal memory (e.g. microSD) are supported by Kindle Fire? I'm looking for cameras so my 94 year-old mom with macular degeneration can watch birds at her feeder on her Kindle Fire. I want a camera that can store video locally so she doesn't need to pay for a separate security hub cloud storage, to watch birds, review video and take pictures.